# Are second-person edits supposed to push a question to the main page?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

A new user asked ["When do rockets push back on matter?"](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37486/26446), which as originally written seemed to push a particular point of view, rather than pose a genuine question.  It subsequently garnered a large number of downvotes.  The author was also abrasive when replying to others' comments.

I felt that the question had potential to be improved, and I [edited](https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/37486/revisions) the title, body, and tags of the question.  It was my hope that those who downvoted the question may reconsider their votes with the new version.

It was my understanding that edits will bump a question to the site main page, so it will be seen by others.  However, that did not happen with my edit.  **Are second-person edits supposed to push a question to the site main page?**

Full disclosure: I also wrote [an answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37512/26446) to the question, which was positively received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ["What can cause a question to be bumped?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/228367) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> †Questions with sufficiently low score will not show on the homepage when either they or their answers are edited, though they will still be shown on the Questions page. The "sufficiently low" threshold is -4 on main sites and -8 on meta sites